# How to get return value of a stored procedure to WCF in VB

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a stored procedure which will return a value of 1 if the record exists and if not return a value of 0.

```
DECLARE @Exists INT

IF EXISTS(SELECT EID FROM dbo.tblRoster WHERE EID = @EID)
    BEGIN
        SET @Exists = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Exists  = 0
    END
    RETURN @Exists
END
```

This is the function that I have created on my WCF Service.

```
Dim dbString As String = BlastConstring()
Dim con As New SqlConnection(dbString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim result As Boolean
con.Open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "SearchUserRoster"
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@EID", EID))

result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
Return result
con.Close()
```

The response on my WCF Test Client always returns false. But on my MSSMS it returns the correct value on both cases.

Comment: Change it to `select @Exists` instead of `RETURN @Exists`

Comment: Return codes are supposed to denote success vs error, not communicate data, but you can add another SqlParameter named @Exists and make the ParameterDirection ReturnValue.